# T-SQL - IF true then run sp_send_dbmail ELSE do nothing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, rowcount, sp-send-dbmail

I've tried several different approaches based on posts Google spit out. But I just can't get it to work.
I'm running a select statement and the results are being emailed to the recipient by using sp_send_dbmail.
This works perfectly fine. What I want to accomplish, is that no email goes out if the select statement comes back with 0 rows. 
I've tried many things, one example:

```
    Select Statement    --The select statement is at the top of the code
    IF @@rowcount = 0     -- followed by the IF statement
    begin
    return
    end
    ELSE
    begin
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    end
```

Running above example, I do not get an error, but in either case, 0 or not 0, it sends the email off.

how do I encapsulate the sp.send_dbmail into an IF statement based on if a select statement comes back with zero results?

Thanks!

Comment: "`esex`"? "`sp.send_dbmail`"? I *assume* you mean `EXEC` and `sys.sp_send_dbmail`. Also, a `BEGIN` should follow your `ELSE`. These all look like typographical errors, as the above will certainly give you errors. `esex` isn't a valid keyword, and I *doubt* that there's an object `send_dbmail` on the schema `sp` in your database.

Comment: Yes 'exec' and msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail .
The exec was a typo, the rest is accurate and working without an error though. There is a begin after the else.

Comment: Then [edit] your question. if you include typos in your code that you say "is working", when it clearly won't, then it's likely to get downvoted or closed as a typographical error.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
IF EXISTS([Select Statement])
BEGIN
exec sp.send_dbmail
END
```

Comment: should have provided more detail. Here's the working select statement without the IF statement:

```
set @query='
SELECT table1.columnA , convert(date,table.column) as columnheader
  FROM table.column

  inner join table  on table.column.column = table.column 
  inner join table on table.column = table.column
  
  where table.column  like ''ABC'' and prefix != ''XYZ''

  and DATE between dateadd(day,+30,getdate())  and dateadd(day,+31,getdate()) 
  order by DATE 
  ' 
```